# Why does fgets hang on a certain url on wamp, but is fine on mamp?

Tags: php, fgets, freeze

I have a script that reads RSS feeds using fopen & fgets.

When trying to the feed at: http://rss.fok.nl/feeds/nieuws my script hangs until the max_timeout of the PHP is reached.

The thing is:

- it worked perfectly (on the same url) until today.
- it still works on my development mac MAMP server.
- it doesn't work on the production WAMP server (php 5.2.8)

I tried fread with no success.

any ideas?

Comment: first time I have ever seen the acronym MAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's more of a workaround than an answer, but I had to resort to it.
I used the following to switch over to curl, using this function:

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    if ($contents) return $contents;
        else return FALSE;
}
```

I found it here: http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

btw, in case anyone wants to dig deeper, according to other reports of fgets hanging, it seems it has something to do with the 'feof' or lack thereof...

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps try to debug your connection using wireshark ([Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/)).** This should give you the reason. Perhaps the webserver is blocking your requests because of the user-agent.

Can you download the file manually on the Windows machine?